# How do I know If my traffic is getting logged in VPN

Tags: security, vpn, privacy, privacy-protection, juniper

My corporate uses Juniper VPN connection.
How could I know if they are tracking all my network activities.

If I use vpn I can asses almost all sites, unlike in office.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no way to tell.

Comment: Also, assume they can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are connected to VPN, your company's IT department can track all of your network activities.  VPN stands for Virtual Private Network, and creates a secured connection over the Internet to your employer.  Your employer has the ability to, and may enforce, all Internet traffic to be routed through that same VPN connection.

Even if your employer is *not* tracking your network activities while you are on VPN, you should *still* assume anything you do on a work computer is trackable.  If your laptop is provided by your work, it is quite possible utilities are installed on the local computer itself to track activities.

If you are doing something you would prefer your employer not see, the only safe option is to use a personal computer / tablet / phone on a private Internet connection.

Comment: I was using my personal laptop, unfortunately I accessed porn.
Anything I can do now ? I am damn scared now :'(

Comment: Anyway I can find out if my employes is tracking my network activities. I work for a big corporate. I assume they do this :(

Comment: Somebody help me, I am feeling very bad :(

Comment: First. you could say that you forgot to shut off the VPN when you were done.  Or you could say a friend took the computer away from you while you were using it.  Companies that track web usage typically try to filter it as well.  Thus, if you were able to access porn, and they aren't blocking it, they may not be closely tracking it.  Lay low, be a model employee for the next 30 to 60 days, and be more careful in the future.  Send your IT department a nice holiday gift, and good luck.

Comment: If the activity has already been logged by your company's IT department, then there's not much you can do to get rid of those records.  Things you should do: 1. Don't do it again. 2. If your manager talks to you about it, apologize sincerely, and don't do it again.  Don't worry yourself to death; you can't do much to change the situation now, and worrying won't help anything. 3. If you are found out, accept the consequences, and don't do it again.

Comment: For further help with this issue see workplace.stackexchange.com.

Comment: All of the above. Plus, next time, use your own VPN inside their VPN.